# Custom headers removed when submitting request via proxy

Tags: proxy

I'm using `Websphere Portal` and trying to make an `AJAX` request via the `Proxy` but getting `404` status code.

When I issue the request below with my custom headers set I get `404`:

```
GET http://proxy.com:10039/wps/proxy/https/server.com/cart/@self
```

But if I issue the same request not routed through the proxy, I get 200

```
GET https://server.com/cart/@self
```

Why is the proxy removing my headers?

I logged all headers on target server and see that the headers are actually removed when they pass through the proxy:

```
{accept=*/*, accept-encoding=gzip,deflate,sdch, accept-language=en-US,en;q=0.8, cache-control=no-cache, connection=keep-alive, host=server.com, pragma=no-cache, user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36}
```

Here is my proxy config:

```
<policy url="{$digital_data_connector_policy}" basic-auth-support="true" name="digital_data_connector">
    <actions>
        <method>GET</method>
        <method>HEAD</method>
        <method>POST</method>
        <method>DELETE</method>
        <method>PUT</method>
    </actions>
    <headers>
        <header>User-Agent</header>
        <header>Accept*</header>
        <header>Content*</header>
        <header>Authorization*</header>
        <header>Set-Cookie</header>
        <header>If-Modified-Since</header>
        <header>If-None-Match</header>
        <header>If-Unmodified-Since</header>
        <header>X-Method-Override</header>
        <header>Set-Cookie</header>
        <header>MyCustomToken</header>
        <header>MyCustomTokenPart2</header>
    </headers>
    <meta-data>
        <name>forward-http-errors</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </meta-data>
    <meta-data>
        <name>forward-credentials-from-vault</name>
        <value>true</value>
    </meta-data>
</policy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My changes to `proxy-config.xml` where not picked up until the `update-outbound-http-connection-config` task was run.